# Does this discrete distribution have a name?

Tags: probability, terminology, discrete-data, distributions

Does this discrete distribution have a name? For $i \in 1...N$

$f(i) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j = i}^N \frac{1}{j}$

I came across this distribution from the following: I have a list of $N$ items ranked by some utility function. I want to randomly select one of the items, biasing toward the start of the list. So, I first choose an index $j$ between 1 and $N$ uniformly. I then select an item between indices 1 and $j$. I believe this process results in the above distribution.

Comment: This is not a distribution: it is not normalized.

Comment: @whuber I thought so at first (and commented before I realized that I had misunderstood and removed the comment), but it turned out I misunderstood the definition. Unless I have a further misunderstanding, it is a normalized probability mass function.

Comment: It is normalized.  1/1 will appear in the sum exactly once (it will be in  f(1)).  1/2 will appear exactly twice (it will be in f(1) and f(2)).  etc.  So the sum of all those sums will be N and the normalizing constant is shown as 1/N.  checks out.

Comment: More to the point, though, I don't know what this distro is called.  I also don't know how the process you described leads to this distro.  One thought I had is that it sounds like a discrete version of a stick-breaking process, which is very googlable.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks.  I was reading this on my phone, which did not render $f$ clearly enough.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have a discretized version of the negative log distribution, that is, the distribution whose support is $[0, 1]$ and whose pdf is $f(t) = - \log t$.

To see this, I'm going to redefine your random variable to take values in the set $\{ 0, 1/N, 2/N, \ldots, 1 \}$ instead of $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, N \}$ and call the resulting distribution $T$.  Then, my claim is that

$$ Pr\left( T = \frac{t}{N} \right) \rightarrow - \frac{1}{N} \log \left( \frac{t}{N} \right) $$

as $N, t \rightarrow \infty$ while $\frac{t}{N}$ is held (approximately) constant.

First, a little simulation experiment demonstrating this convergence.  Here's a small implementation of a sampler from your distribution:

```
t_sample <- function(N, size) {
  bounds <- sample(1:N, size=size, replace=TRUE)
  samples <- sapply(bounds, function(t) {sample(1:t, size=1)})
  samples / N
}
```

Here's a histogram of a large sample taken from your distribution:

```
ss <- t_sample(100, 200000)
hist(ss, freq=FALSE, breaks=50)
```

[image]

and here's the logarithmic pdf overlaid:

```
linsp <- 1:100 / 100
lines(linsp, -log(linsp))
```

[image]

To see why this convergence occurs, start with your expression

$$ Pr \left( T = \frac{t}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=t}^N \frac{1}{j} $$

and multiply and divide by $N$

$$ Pr \left( T = \frac{t}{N} \right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=t}^N \frac{N}{j} \frac{1}{N} $$

The summation is now a Riemann sum for the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, integrated from $\frac{t}{N}$ to $1$.  That is, for large $N$,

$$ Pr \left( T = \frac{t}{N} \right) \approx \frac{1}{N} \int_{\frac{t}{N}}^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = - \frac{1}{N} \log \left( \frac{t}{N} \right)$$

which is the expression I wanted to arrive at.

Comment: You're extremely welcome.  This was a great question and I had a lot of fun working it out.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be related to the Whitworth distribution. (I don't believe it is the Whitworth distribution, since if I remember right, that's the distribution of a set of ordered values, but it seems to be connected to it, and relies on the same summation-scheme.)

There's some discussion of the Whitworth (and numerous references) in

Anthony Lawrance and Robert Marks, (2008)
"Firm size distributions in an industry with constrained resources,"
*Applied Economics*, vol. 40, issue 12, pages 1595-1607

(There looks to be a working paper version [here](http://www.agsm.edu.au/bobm/papers/lawrance-marks-AE1.pdf))

Also see

Nancy L Geller, (1979)
A test of significance for the Whitworth distribution,
*Journal of the American Society for Information Science*, Vol.30(4), pp.229-231

Comment: To make this answer self-contained, could you provide a definition of the Whitworth distribution and perhaps supply a few words of explanation concerning the connection you see?

Comment: @whuber Yes, it should be a comment as it stands. I'll edit some details in but it's going to end up a good deal longer.

Comment: Just some kind of definition would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was understood, but nevertheless that will be the outcome.